# What is an algorithm to find intersection of two linear equations?

Tags: algorithm, equation

I'm struggling to figure out an algorithm to find the intersection of two linear equations like:

```
f(x)=2x+4

g(x)=x+2
```

I'd like to use the method where you set f (x)=g (x) and solve x, and I'd like to stay away from cross product.

Does anyone have any suggestion to how an algorithm like that would look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your input lines are in slope-intercept form, an algorithm is an over-kill as there is a direct formula to calculate their point of intersection. It's given on a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Intersection_of_two_lines) and you can understand it as explained below.

> **Given the equations of the lines:** The x and y coordinates of the
>   point of intersection of two non-vertical lines can easily be found
>   using the following substitutions and rearrangements.
>
> Suppose that two lines have the equations y = ax + c and y = bx + d where a
>   and b are the slopes (gradients) of the lines and where c and d are
>   the y-intercepts of the lines. At the point where the two lines
>   intersect (if they do), both y coordinates will be the same, hence the
>   following equality:
>
> ax + c = bx + d.
>
> We can rearrange this expression in order to extract the
>   value of x,
>
> ax - bx = d - c, and so,
>
> *x = (d-c)/(a-b).*
>
> To find the y coordinate, all we need to do is substitute the value of x into > either one of the two line equations. For example, into the first:
>
> *y=(a*(d-c)/(a-b))+c.*
>
> Hence, the **Point of Intersection is *{(d-c)/(a-b), (a*(d-c)/(a-b))+c}***
>
> **Note:** *If a = b then the two lines are parallel. If c ≠ d as well, the lines
>   are different and there is no intersection, otherwise the two lines are
>   identical.*

Answer (score 3):

Given:
ax + b = cx + d

> ax = cx + d - b
>
> ax - cx = d - b
>
> x(a - c) = d - b
>
> Therefore, x = (d - b) / (a - c)

In your example, let a = 2, b = 4, c = 1 d = 2

> x = (2 - 4) / (2 - 1)
>
> x = -2 / 1
>
> x = -2

Comment: Don't forget to test `a != c`, otherwise you'll end with a division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

General solution. Let

f(x) = a1x + b1  .......    g(x) = a2x + b2

Special cases:

- a1 == a2 and b1 == b2 : lines coincide
- a1 == a2 and b1 != b2 : lines are parallel, no intersection

General case: a1 != a2

X = (b2 - b1) / (a1 - a2)  ....and...   Y = (a1b2 - a2b1) / (a1 - a2)

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember what cross products are in the context of equations.

One way to solve these is to set them equal to each other, solve for `x`, then use that value to solve for `y`:

```
2x + 4 = x + 2
2x + 2 = x
     x = -2
     y = f(x)
       = g(x)
       = x + 2
       = -2 + 2
       = 0
```

Solution: `(-2, 0)`